# Compare two point arrays and check if there are any same items

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I have a 4x4 board. And I need to create 2 random `Point` variables and then see that those values have not been randomised before.

I have 2 `Point` array variables, called `Item1` and `Item2`

> Let's say that after the first loop I have `Item1[0]` = (1,0) and `Item2[0]` = (3,2)
>   
>  at the second loop I should not get (1,0) and (3,2) as values
>   
>  at the third loop I should not get items from first, or second loop

Now, for the coming loops I need to find a way so that the above items are not selected again!

My code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Point[] Item1 = new Point[8];
Point[] Item2 = new Point[8];
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
//create coordinates for the first item
    Item1[x].X = rnd.Next(8);
    Item1[x].Y = rnd.Next(8);
//create coordinates for the second item
    Item2[x].X = rnd.Next(8);
    Item2[x].Y = rnd.Next(8);
}
```

I was thinking on creating a `List<Point>` and add each point in the list. But I have no idea how to check all items on the list, and how to find that those items do not match.

Thank you.

p.s. I want to create a memory game. And that's why I need 2 points at a time and that's why it's important that I have unique points.

### EDIT: Thanks. For future reference, This is how I did it.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Point[] Item1 = new Point[8];
Point[] Item2 = new Point[8];
List<Point> usedPoint = new List<Point>();
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
        do
        {
            Item1[x].X = rnd.Next(8);
            Item1[x].Y = rnd.Next(8);
        }
        while(usedPoint.Contains(new Point(Item1[x].X,Item1[x].Y))== true);
        usedPoint.Add(new Point(Item1[x].X,Item1[x].Y));
        do
        {
            Item2[x].X = rnd.Next(8);
            Item2[x].Y = rnd.Next(8);
        }
        while (usedPoint.Contains(new Point(Item2[x].X, Item2[x].Y))== true);
        usedPoint.Add(new Point(Item2[x].X, Item2[x].Y));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to solve your issue.
If the number of points grow you large you should consider using an Hashtable for performance sake.
If you want to use a `List<Point> list`, you can use the `list.Contains(new Point(x,y))` to check if such point is present.

More references about `List<T>.Contains` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could use Hashset for performance
quick code sample: you will need something like that

```
var random = new Random();
var randomSet = new HashSet<int>();
const int size = 8 * 4; // 4 because for each coordinate and each item
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    var r = random.Next();
    if (!randomSet.Contains(r)) {
        randomSet.Add(r);
    }
}
var uniqueRandowmNumbers = randomSet.ToArray();
int k = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{

//create coordinates for the first item
    Item1[x].X = uniqueRandowmNumbers[k++];
    Item1[x].Y = uniqueRandowmNumbers[k++];
//create coordinates for the second item
    Item2[x].X = uniqueRandowmNumbers[k++];
    Item2[x].Y = uniqueRandowmNumbers[k++];
}
```